# Syntax issue with using Multer in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, file-upload, multer

i've been using this tutorial :

https://medium.com/@mahesh_joshi/reactjs-nodejs-upload-image-how-to-upload-image-using-reactjs-and-nodejs-multer-918dc66d304c

To upload a file from React client side to Node.js server side. 
I'm havng an issue with the POST route given in the tutorial, 
VS Code shows a syntax error when pasting it. Can anyone re-arrange it? 
This is the route :

```
router.post("/upload", {
upload(req, res, (err) => {
  console.log("Request ---", req.body);
  console.log("Request file ---", req.file);//Here you get file.
  /*Now do where ever you want to do*/
  if(!err)
     return res.send(200).end();
});
};);
```

Comment: `router.post("/upload", {` ... what is this `{`?  a random floating block of code for no reason? ... the start of an object declaration? ... I don't understand (neither does the compiler)

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this

```
router.post('/upload', function (req, res) {
    upload(req, res, function (err) {
        console.log("Request ---", req.body);
        console.log("Request file ---", req.file);//Here you get file.
        /*Now do where ever you want to do*/
        if(!err) {
            return res.send(200).end();
        }
    })
})
```