# TypeError using Materialize-CSS with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, materialize

i'm having a problem using Materialize-CSS carousel. 
The standard way to create the carousel is :

```
<div class="carousel">
<a class="carousel-item" href="#one!"><img 
src="https://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/1"></a>
<a class="carousel-item" href="#two!"><img 
src="https://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/2"></a>
<a class="carousel-item" href="#three!"><img 
src="https://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/3"></a>
</div>
```

But I want to create a carousel item for every item in an array named 
"products" hence i'm trying this code in the JSX :

```
<div className="carousel">

{generalStore.products.map(p =>
<a className="carousel-item"><img src={p.pic} /></a>)}

</div>
```

p,pic == image url

But this returns an error :

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'clientWidth' of undefined
```

Ant ideas to solve this? 
Thanks

Comment: Is `p.pic` the src url for the image? I think we need to see the products structure

Comment: Hi, yes it is. Editing for clearance

Comment: Could You please share the screenshot or more information about this error? Browser console usually shows the file and line of code where error occurred.

Comment: Hi Roman, this is a screenshot : 

https://imgur.com/bArgM40 

Is it helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be implemented in materializeCSS also. 
For this, you need to do `npm install materialize-css@next`. After this, you need to import the materialize-css in your component JS file.

To use the Javascript materialize-css components, a reference of these components has to be made in `componentDidMount()` has to be made and then it can be used in `ref`.

[CodeSandBox - Working Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-fermi-xl82y)

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import M from "materialize-css";
import "materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.min.css";
import data from "./data.json";

class Carousel extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const options = {
      duration: 300,
      onCycleTo: () => {
        console.log("New Slide");
      }
    };
    M.Carousel.init(this.Carousel, options);
  }

  renderThis = () => {
    return data.map(i => (
      <a key={i.url} className="carousel-item">
        <img src={i.url} />
      </a>
    ));
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div
        ref={Carousel => {
          this.Carousel = Carousel;
        }}
        className="carousel"
      >
        {this.renderThis()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Carousel;
```

Comment: Well if it's working then please accept the answer so that the question will be marked as answered.

Comment: Accepted. Sorry, didn't even know I need to mark it

Comment: It's okay, I think you should also mark other answers which helped you in solving your problem :) Example - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56410236/syntax-issue-with-using-multer-in-node-js